# Can I use ReviewBoard with an svn repository on a different machine?

Tags: svn, review-board

I installed ReviewBoard on a machine running Ubuntu and I want to integrate it with a Subversion Repository (SVN) which is currently running on a different machine running redhat.

Is this possible?  How do I connect ReviewBoard on one machine to a Subversion repository on a different machine?

Answer (score 1):

It`s possible. You need get your SVN repository`s URL, and then go to the review-board`s admin page, there you can see a repository tab, you can connect you SVN repository with review-board there. Just need your URL, username and password. It works fine, my team has been using it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the instructions in this [link](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.0/admin/configuration/repositories/#determining-repository-information) for review board guide to get your SVN URL.

simply To get the root URL 

`$cd /path/to/working/copy/of/SVN/repository
$svn info`

The root URL will be defined as the *Repository Root:*

This is the review board [wiki link](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.0/admin/configuration/repositories/) that explains the steps to connect any repository type to the review board.

It is expected you have the administrative privilege to access the repository add page.

**EDITED**